# KGDB, Remote connection Error

Tags: gdb, kgdb

Im very New to KGDB, Im getting problem when im connecting the target from Host, Getting The following Error.

```
(gdb) target remote /dev/ttyUSB0
Remote debugging using /dev/ttyUSB0
Ignoring packet error, continuing...
warning: unrecognized item "swreak" in "qSupported" response
warning: unrecognized item "ReloInsn" in "qSupported" response
warning: unrecognized item "QTread'
[3]kdb> " in "qSupported" response
Bogus trace status reply from target: qTStatus
...
```

#

The Procedure Im following is :

> ```
> [Target] stty -F /dev/ttyS0 115200
> [Host] stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
> ```
>
> Make sure the serial connection works on both direction. You can use:
>
> ```
> [Host] cat /dev/ttyUSB0
> [Target] echo 'from TARGET to HOST' > /dev/ttyS0
>
> [Target] cat /dev/ttyS0
> [Host] echo 'from HOST to TARGET' > /dev/ttyUSB0
> ```
>
> You should see the messages on both side of machine. If not, there
>   might be some problems on the cable or driver.
>
> #### Compile Kernel
>
> Enable KGDB* , KGDB_SERIAL*, KGDB_USB*, DEBUG_INFO, DEBUG_INFO_DWARF4,
>   MAGIC_SYSRQ in the kernel config. Compile and install on the TARGET.
>
> The main purpose here is to enable KGDB feature & preserve debug
>   information in vmlinux.
>
> #### agent-proxy Setup
>
> agent-proxy acts as a proxy for the TARGET's serial port. It splits up
>   the serial port for multiplexing. One for primary console I/O, the
>   other for GDB session. Thus, we can work on both simultaneously. You
>   should run the agent-proxy on HOST machine.
>
> ```
> git clone http://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/kernel/kgdb/agent-proxy.git
> cd agent-proxy ; make
> ./agent-proxy 5550^5551 0 /dev/ttyUSB0,115200
> ```
>
> This will redirect:
>
> - TARGET's console to HOST:5550
> - TARGET's kgdb listening port to HOST:5551
>
> #### Start To Debug
>
> First, open the primary console:
>
> ```
> [Host] telnet localhost 5550
> ```
>
> Entering the kdb mode, either by:
>
> ```
> [Target] echo ttyS0,115200 > /sys/module/kgdboc/parameters/kgdboc
> [Target] dmesg | tail
> ```
>
> (you should see KGDB: Registered I/O driver kgdboc, otherwise it
>   failed)
>
> ```
> [Target] echo g >/proc/sysrq-trigger
> Host> gdb vmlinux
> (gdb) target remote localhost:5551
> Remote debugging using localhost:5551
> kgdb_breakpoint () at kernel/debug/debug_core.c:1072
> 1072             wmb(); /* Sync point after breakpoint */
> (gdb)
> ```

#

when i type kgdb in target mission it is getting error as Permission denied as shown below

```
[3]kdb> kgdb
diag: -22: Permission denied
```

..., I would appreciate the clear answer in steps..., Thanks in advance

Comment: Please properly format your question, it increases the readability: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0):

```
diag: -22: Permission denied
```

That error means that access to debugger functions is [prohibited](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/b2c91128212a4c1a36bd3085191bff21a34324be/kernel/debug/kdb/kdb_main.c#L513) by default in you kernel. In order to unlock debugger you need exec this command:

> echo 1 > /sys/module/kdb/parameters/cmd_enable

or add a Kernel Boot Parameter:

> kdb.cmd_enable=1

More info [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/9c7db5004280767566e91a33445bf93aa479ef02/lib/Kconfig.kgdb#L77)